# server-side only action in meteor (accessible on client-side)

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I am learning meteor and did the to-do project in meteor's tutorial. I was wondering how to hide some data from the client since files outside the server folder can be seen from the client. 
Let's say a user does register to the app and want to call an external api to fetch some data and i use a secret to do so, and I dont want to expose this secret. Then I want to add this data that i got to the user collection.
Actually I use Meteor methods (ran by client and server).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a Meteor [Method](http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html). Put the code for this method in `/server` and it won't be shared with the client. You call the method from the client using `Meteor.call()`

Also note that it's good practice to put secrets in a `settings` file and to manage this file outside of your version control system. See [Making Use of Settings.json](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/making-use-of-settings-json/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I managed to call the method from a file inside the /imports/api/myfile.js `Meteor.call('taskserver', text, function (error, result) { 
     console.log(result);
    });` but the console log is undefined on the client's console but works in the meteor console. This is the server method :
`Meteor.methods({
  taskserver: function (text) {
    return "some return value";
  }
});`